# Unmarshal JSON object published over MQTT in Go

Tags: json, go, mqtt, unmarshalling

I am receiving sensor data over MQTT. I want to check if the temperature is over 20 degrees, and if it is, send a message.

```
var f MQTT.MessageHandler = func(client MQTT.Client, msg MQTT.Message) {
    type Data struct {
        Sensor string        `json:"sensor"`
        Temp []int           `json: "temperature"`
        Hum []int           `json: "humidity"`
    }
    var sensorData []Data
    message := ""
    err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Payload(), &sensorData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }else {

    //access certain element in the Data struct
        for _, i := range sensorData {
            if i.Temp[2] > 20 { //where the temperature is stored
                fmt.Println("Temperature too high")
                message = "Temperature too high"
            }else{
                fmt.Println("Perfect temperature")
                message = "Perfect temperature"
        }
    }

    }

    // Publish further instructions to "sensor/instruction"
    token := client.Publish("sensor/instruction", 0, false, message)
    token.Wait()
}
```

Currently I am publishing **two** JSON objects to be received. I think part of the problem is distinguishing between the two objects. This is the error I am getting `panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Data`. These are the JSON objects I am publishing to a topic:

```
{'sensor': 'DHT22', 'temperature': [22.7, 22.7, 22.8], 'humidity': [51.9, 52.0, 52.0]}
{'actuator': 'arduinoLED', 'blink': ['false', 'false', 'false']}
```

The `msg.Payload()` gives

```
{"sensor": "DHT22", "temperature": [22.9, 22.9, 22.9], "humidity": [50.9, 50.9, 50.9]}
{"actuator": "arduinoLED", "blink": ["false", "false", "false"]
```

These objects are published constantly in a **loop**. I want to unmarshal the first object and access a specific element.

Comment: Can you print and share `msg.Payload()` and people can check if it is a valid and **one** Json object.

Comment: Since you are passing a slice of `Data` but it is an object first. use `Data` struct not slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Slice vs single object**

You are declaring a slice:

```
var sensorData []Data
```

But then your payload is not an array but rather only one object:

```
{'sensor': 'DHT22', 'temperature': [22.7, 22.7, 22.8], 'humidity': [51.9, 52.0, 52.0]}
```

So that error message is telling you it cannot unmarshal a single object as a slice.

Try changing that declaration to:

```
var sensorData Data
```

Then, instead of iterating over it, you need to just check that one instance of the data.

**Additional mismatches between the payload and the struct type**

After that, you'll probably get another error since the `temperature` and `humidity` array seem to contain decimal numbers:

```
`{'sensor': 'DHT22', 'temperature': [22.7, 22.7, 22.8], 'humidity': [51.9, 52.0, 52.0]`
```

But you are declaring those as `int` slices in your code:

```
Temp []int           `json: "temperature"`
Hum []int           `json: "humidity"`
```

So you'll need to change those to be `[]float64`

**Differentiating the two different payloads**

About differentiating the two object types, it'd be better if you try to do that, but even if you don't, Go's `json` library will ignore problems if field names do not match, so what will happen is that when de-serializing your `actuator` payloads into `Data`, all fields will have their default values, but no error will be received.

This check will probably throw a `panic`, cause the array will be empty in that case:

```
if i.Temp[2] > 20
```

One "hacky" way of solving this issue would be to only process the data if the `sensor` field is not a blank string.

Assuming you always receive a sensor name in the `sensor` messages, the only case when that will result in an empty string is if you just processed one of the other messages.

Comment: I added two more elements to my struct : `Actuator string json:"actuator"` and `Blink []string json: "blink"` to accommodate for the second JSON object. However when I do `fmt.Println(sensorData)`, I get `{DHT22 [22.9 22.9 22.9] [51.3 51.2 51.2]  []}` `{ [] [] arduinoLED [false false false]}`. It seems there are only four elements in each object but my struct has 5 parameters? Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Melissa, try printing it like this to get the field names as well for easier debugging (note the plus sign): fmt.Printf("%+v\n", sensorData)

Comment: I get this: `{Sensor:DHT22 Temperature:[22.8 22.8 22.8] Humidity:[51.3 51.1 51] Actuator: Blink:[]}`
`{Sensor: Temperature:[] Humidity:[] Actuator:arduinoLED Blink:[false false false]}`

Comment: ok, your five fields are listed on each object you are printing, right? In the first one only "Sensor", "Temperature" and "Humidity" have values (the other two are blank), in the second one the opposite is true (Actuator and Blink have values, the other three are blank). It looks like the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons for your error One is you have `float` value for temperature and humidity but you are passing slice of `int`

```
type Data struct {
    Sensor string        `json:"sensor"`
    Temp []int           `json: "temperature"` // this should be []float64
    Hum []int           `json: "humidity"` // this should be []float64
}
```

Other is there are two objects in `msg.Payload` which is not a slice of `Data` struct. Working code.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Sensor string    `json:"sensor"`
    Temp   []float64 `json:"temperature"`
    Hum    []float64 `json:"humidity"`
}

func main() {
    bytes := []byte(`{
        "sensor": "DHT22", 
        "temperature": [22.7, 22.7, 22.8], 
        "humidity": [51.9, 52.0, 52.0]
    }`)

    var sensorData Data
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &sensorData); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sensorData)

}
```

Check working code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gontMGnCkuX)